# Calling one module into another module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python modules called main.py and black.py :

Main.py content as follows :

```
import os,sys,string,time
import subprocess,commands,re
import random
import black
class bcolors:
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNBOLD = '033[0m'
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
def disable(self):
    self.BOLD = ''
    self.UNBOLD = ''
    self.HEADER = ''
    self.OKBLUE = ''
    self.OKGREEN = ''
    self.WARNING = ''
    self.FAIL = ''
    self.ENDC = ''
def print_menu():
        #subprocess.call("tput clear")
        print " "
        #print bcolors.OKBLUE + (35 * '-') + bcolors.OKBLUE
        print bcolors.OKBLUE + '\t\t\t\t' + (52 * '*') + bcolors.OKBLUE
        print ("\t\t\t\t\t\tM A I N - M E N U")
        print '\t\t\t\t' + (52 * '*')
        print ("\t\t\t\t 0. Enter POD Name(s).")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 1. QUIT")
        print '\t\t\t\t' + (52 * '*') + bcolors.ENDC
        is_valid=0
        while not is_valid:
                try :
                        choice = int ( raw_input('Enter your choice [0-24] : ') )
                        is_valid = 1
                except ValueError, e :
                        print ("'%s' is not a valid integer." % e.args[0].split(": ")[1])
        return choice
########## M A I N #####################
rUser=commands.getoutput("id -un").strip()
if rUser != "oracle":
        print bcolors.FAIL + "  Login as mc_admin to run the script. Exiting .." + bcolors.ENDC
        exit ()
else:
        os.system("tput clear")
        choice = print_menu()
###################
global podList    # 
podList = None    #
###################
while choice >= 0 and choice < 1:
        if choice == 0:
                pPODName()
black.blackout()
```

and black.py content as follows:

```
def blackout():
    def pPODName():
        global podList
        podList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of PODS : ')).upper().strip()
        if podList:
            try:
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -p " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                prodP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if prodP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Production Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + prodP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -t " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                stagP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if stagP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Stage/Test Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + stagP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -d " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                devP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if devP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Dev/Upgrade Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + devP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -i " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                intstgP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if intstgP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Internal Staging Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + intstgP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -r " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                prtnP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if prtnP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Partner Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + prtnP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -s " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                stbyP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if stbyP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "DR/Standby Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + stbyP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -u " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                unalloP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if unalloP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Unallocated Pods [Status: Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + unalloP + bcolors.ENDC
                cmd = "/fsnadmin/f516478/romeshar/myfolder/PodDetails.sh -l " + "\"" + podList + "\""
                trlP = commands.getoutput(cmd).strip()
                if trlP:
                    print bcolors.FAIL + "Trial Pods [Status: Customer Active|Dev Post Provisioning|Cloud Ops Provisioning]: \n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + trlP + bcolors.ENDC
            except OSError:
                print bcolors.FAIL + "Could not invoke Pod Details Script. " + bcolors.ENDC
                podList = vPodName(podList)
            print bcolors.FAIL + "\nYou Have Entered PodList as: " + podList + "\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            uResp = str(raw_input('Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] : ')).upper().strip()
            #if uResp == "NO" or uResp == "N":
            if uResp != "YES" and uResp != 'Y':
                pPODName ()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    blackout()
```

I want black.py module to be called in main.py but when I am running main.py I am getting the following error:

```
[oracle@localhost tmp]$ ./main.py
****************************************************
                M A I N - M E N U
****************************************************
 0. Enter POD Name(s).
 1. QUIT

Enter your choice [0-24] : 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 131, in <module>
    pPODName()
NameError: name 'pPODName' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

`pPODName` has not been defined as far as main.py can tell.

### Firstly

`pPODName` is defined within another function, so only that function is aware of it. This is referred to as being in local scope. Basically anything defined within a function is only accessible to that function, and nothing else.

**For an example:**

```
def test():
    def test_local():
        return 3
    return test_local()
```

Running the function test gives you

```
>>> test()
3
```

However running the function `test_local`

```
>>> test_local()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test_local' is not defined
```

### Secondly

Secondly, when importing modules, you need to either qualify them with the module name, like you have done with `black.blackout()`, of you need to use:

```
from black import *
```

Although personally I don't like that, it makes it hard to see where methods are coming from.

### Fix

For `main.py` to be able to call `pPODName`, it must be defined within the module as a whole, e.g.:

```
def blackout()
    #do stuff here

def pPODNAME()
    #do other stuff here
    #note the indentation level is the same as blackout
```

and you must call it with

```
black.pPODName()
```

From main.py

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know what edition can I do in my code to call pPODName fucntion.

Comment: See my edits, however I can't give you a full fix on what you're trying to do. I imagine you had `pPODName` nested within another function for a reason, if this is the case, you can't call it from `main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some programming hierarchy level mistake 
why  pPODName is inner function of blackout ? 
and has James said- if you are using outer and inner function the outer needs to call the inner.

I suggest you to use regular function in black.py
blackout function does nothing except containing the pPODName so you don't need it

Shlomy